# Allow-Deselect not working in Chosen-Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-chosen

Problem in Angular:

```
 element.chosen(); // works

 element.chosen({allow_single_deselect: true}); // doesn't work
```

Works perfectly when implementing 'Chosen' using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){               
    $(".chosen-select").chosen({allow_single_deselect: true}); // works
    $(".chosen-select").chosen(); // also works
```

I'm implementing Chosen Plugin in Angular using [guidelines](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ozyXwLzFYs) illustrated at [angular-chosen](https://github.com/simpulton/angular-chosen).

This is the [Chosen Home Page](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Comment: The same happening with Me.

Comment: Sorry for being a necromancer, just had an idea what could have caused the problem and might help future readers: did you add an empty `<option><option>` inside the `<select>`? The docs state that the first element has to be an empty option otherwise deselection won't work.

Answer (score 1):

To use Chosen with AngularJS, I built a directive to make Angular works with this plugin, but I got the same problem with `allow_single_deselect`.

To force this flag I add these lines in my directive.

```
element.data('chosen').allow_single_deselect = true;
```

It worked.

That's my directive: https://gist.github.com/egermano/7711815